# Source code version number policy

Tags: versioning

I need a guideline or procedure which describe the version number policy for source code as per changes happened(major, minor, Micro), assigning particular version to release, labeling e.t.c

Your guideline in this regards will be highly appreciated....

Answer (score 2):

You have some public interesting guidelines to get you started:

- **[IBM Rational products](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27008656)**
- **[Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Version_Numbering)**
- [OSGi and version numbering in general](http://www.slideshare.net/caniszczyk/osgi-versioning-and-testingppt)
- [Java Sun version numbering](http://alblue.blogspot.com/2008/05/version-numbers-and-jsr277.html)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the Wikipedia article relating this, here it is:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_number

Answer (score 2):

I've always been a fan of the way the Apache folks handle [versioning](http://apr.apache.org/versioning.html).  The Subversion people also adopted a variation of it (can't find the link since they moved web sites), which makes for a consistent, easy to understand methodology.

Comment: The Apache versioning document is good.  Thanks for the pointer.  It has some version detailed discussion of how to handle various kinds of changes.

Answer (score 1):

[Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) is a simple but rigorous and complete method of managing version numbers.  It defines a format like

```
major.minor.patch
```

For example, `1.0.0` or `2.1.2`.  Note that all three primary components are always present, and the components are never padded with zeros.

There is an optional pre-release component like

```
major.minor.patch-pre
```

which can be used for all kinds of pre-release versions, like `1.0.0-alpha.1` or `1.0.0-rc`.

There is an optional build metadata component like

```
major.minor.patch+build
```

that is not considered with respect to ordering versions.

The Semantic Versioning specification clearly defines how version numbers are ordered in precedence, so that all pre-release versions precede the corresponding release version (without the pre-release component).

Take few minutes to carefully read the specification.  It seems simple at first and you might be tempted to skim it without reading it, but there are lots of great aspects to it that are well thought out.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the format `a.b.c.d`, `a` being Major, `b` Minor, `c` Build and `d` Revision (even though MS swaps those last two around).

Major and Minor *should* be set by yourself. Use Build and Revision or just Revision to relate back to the changeset/revision in your source control system.

Reason to use a combination of Build and Revision for this is because you may run into issues where the revision is too high a number to be used on certain platforms (thinking of AssemblyVersion in .NET here, 4 `Int16` parts). So you could use SCS revision div 1000 for `c` and revision mod 1000 for `d`.

That way, from any version number (really just from Build and Revision parts), you will always be able to get to a unique state of your source code.