# Source control: what version numbering should be used for branches?

Tags: version-control, branch, versioning

If a branch is created in source control, what version number should be used if there is a release of the branched code?

eg.  If the last version number was v1.2.8 and a branch is created, what should the next version numbers of the branch and the main trunk be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what the branch is for (what development effort it isolate, as described in "[When should you branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100829/when-should-you-branch/2107672#2107672)")

For instance, for a fix which doesn't add any new feature, it could be `v1.2.9`.
But actually the version number policies are :

- very diverse (see this [list for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324518/source-code-version-number-policy/2324540#2324540))
- [can be a bit crazy at time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377655/code-version-change-rules/3377717#3377717)
- not to be mixed with [internal technical revision number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734422/changeset-numbering/734473#734473)
- can be doubled by a [commercial naming strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121795/what-version-numbering-scheme-do-you-recommend/121843#121843)

The important thing to remember is that a label like `vx.y.z` can be generated on *any* branch. It simply marks a stable point in the development life-cycle.

Comment: Ok, so as long as the developers are aware of what the version numbers mean, then it's OK?

Comment: @Craig: yes, it is ok, provided its meaning fits the development effort isolated in said branch.

Comment: if it is just a minor bug-fix/upgrade then shouldn't it just be an increment of the last number: ie. v1.2.10 ?

Comment: @Craig: but you mentioned in your question '`v1.2.8`'... hence my increment: '`v1.2.9`'

Answer (score 2):

In our project we follow the single release branch strategy: release will be always performed on release branch. There can be several development/feature/bug-fixing branches, but we never release the product from those branches. They will first be merged into release branch and release from release branch.

On non-release branch, SNAPSHOT version is always used (we use Maven) and the version name is the branch name . For example on a branch which names `featureX`, the version is `featureX-SNAPSHOT`. On release branch numeric version is used. Version number will be stepped in new release. In this way, we won't be bothered what version number to use in a non-release branch.